# How to read timing diagrams: ak4554 audio serial interface

Tags: audio, serial, embedded, dac, timing

As a newbie I struggle to understand interface timing diagrams of  AK4554.
I am asking this particular example but I believe your answers will enlighten me about how to read any timing diagram.
It is a audio DAC, and here its datasheet: http://www.akm.com/akm/en/file/datasheet/AK4554VT.pdf

In this datasheet it is written that LRCK is clocked at sampling frequency. And data-in is 96 times sampling frequency. The device is 16 bits so what should I do to data-in in rest of 80 cycles? In the datasheet it is not written anywhere that the data is latched at certain time... Should I repeat the data or am I allowed to float? Can I do other tasks in my processor during that time? What is the easy way to produce sound messages while struggling with other tasks in simple microprocessor-peripheral systems?

Comment: I can't readily find your claim of _96 times sampling frequency_ while browsing the datasheet. Figure 4 on page 10 seems reasonably clear to me, if you're looking for how to read the data out. Please point to the part of the datasheet you're having problems with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In this datasheet it is written that LRCK is clocked at sampling frequency.

Yes, LRCK is the sample clock.

> data-in is 96 times sampling frequency.

Nope. Check table 1 on page 9: SCLK should be either 32Fs (which is the minimum for 16 bit stereo, ie 2x16=32 bits per sample) or 64Fs.

Page 7 mentions a minimum period of 1/(96Fs) for SCLK, but this is only a timing spec.

> The device is 16 bits so what should I do to data-in in rest of 80 cycles?

If you use SCLK=32Fs there are no extra cycles. If you use SCLK=64Fs then simply add 16 zero bits as shown on Fig.3 page 10.I suffest using 32Fs since this is simpler.

> In the datasheet it is not written anywhere that the data is latched at certain time...

Simply send the bits as shown in Fig. 4.

> Can I do other tasks in my processor during that time?

Of course! Since your micro has an audio I2S/LJ/RJ interface with DMA, simply set it up and it will play your audio.

If your micro does not have this kind of interface, then use a micro that has one!

> What is the easy way to produce sound messages while struggling with other tasks in simple microprocessor-peripheral systems?

If you want super low quality audio, use your micro's PWM and do it in software. If you want to use that CODEC chip then I supose you want higher quality, so you will have several MBytes of flash to store your samples, and a micro with DMA able to stream them.